# Bash terminal in Visual Studio dotnet not found

Tags: .net-core, wsl-2

I have debian 11 installed in wsl2 on windows 10.  I use the dotnet cli tools in visual studio and cmd windows but much prefer the linux syntax.  The sdk commands are not exposed to wsl apparently as I get "bash: command dotnet not found" errors.  Because WSL is essentially mapping linux commands to windows I don't think I should be installing the dotnet sdk again for linux, but can't really find any confirmation of that.  Anyone here doing this who can advise?  Just don't want to have to maintain two sets of the dotnet sdk if WSL does not require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The sdk commands are not exposed to wsl apparently as I get "bash: command dotnet not found" errors.

That's because WSL *does not* run Windows executables - it is, after all, a *Linux* subsystem.

> I don't think I should be installing the dotnet sdk again for linux

You have two choices:

1. Use the Windows subsystem (drop WSL),
2. install the Linux applications you want to run.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  After install it still doesn't work but for known errors with path_helper . . . so just following the microsoft directions don't really give a persistent working dotnet cli.